# Default group permissions for /var folder

Tags: permissions, chmod

I accidentally ran `sudo chmod -R g+rw /var` instead of `sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www`. This means that for every file, the group owner now has explicit read-write access.

I have already seen an example of [attempting to fix `chown -R www-data:www-data /var`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343245/default-user-group-owner-for-var-folder) but that is a slightly more serious issue that doesn't really apply here. Also the help given doesn't really help me restore the group permission settings to `/var`.

Is there an easy way to set the group permissions back to their defaults? What would you advise I do now? I'd really like to avoid reinstalling if possible.

// edit: I reinstalled Ubuntu. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In principle is practically impossible to go back perfectly. However, there is a script here http://askubuntu.com/a/43636/16395 (not mine!) to copy permissions from another system... maybe could help you with most of the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/var` is used by various processes to write lock files, cache, pid files, log files, ... Some files / sub-directories will need one kind of permissions / ownership, some will need something different.

I'm afraid to tell you that **you cannot solve your problem with only one command** (unless you have a backup of `/var` with all permissions and ownership preserved).

To help you to understand the challenge, here is a printout of my `/var` :

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root      4096 mar 15 21:36 backups
drwxr-xr-x 29 root   root      4096 mar  4 10:53 cache
drwxrwsrwt  2 root   whoopsie  4096 fév  6 20:21 crash
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     12288 oct 27 10:48 games
drwxr-xr-x 98 root   root      4096 mar  4 11:40 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root   staff     4096 oct 20  2009 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root         9 mai 31  2012 lock -> /run/lock
drwxr-xr-x 27 root   root     12288 mar 20 07:44 log
drwxrwsrwt  2 root   mail      4096 jan 29  2013 mail
drwxrwsrwt  2 root   whoopsie  4096 mai 12  2013 metrics
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root      4096 oct 11  2011 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root         4 oct 26 22:52 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x 11 root   root      4096 mai 12  2013 spool
drwxrwxrwt  5 root   root      4096 mar 20 07:52 tmp
drwx------  3 root   bin       4096 mar  9 12:13 webmin
drwxr-xr-x  6 benoit root      4096 oct 31 21:22 www
```

You will remark that some of these directories need to be `setuid` (the s flag in the permissions - `sudo chmod g+s /var/metrics`).
`tmp` will be with the sticky bit (`sudo chmod 1777 /var/tmp`)

And **you still have to go inside each of these directories** !

By the way, setting the ownership of the whole `/var` with read-write rights for the group is a bad idea. This means that if the web server is badly configured, a hacker may have the possibility to read and write the whole `/var` directory.
Remember that under `/var/lib` you will find the data files of MySQL, Postgres, ... if you use it.

If you want to fix the permissions and the ownership without reinstalling the system, you will have to **do a second installation of Ubuntu elsewhere** and check what are the exact permissions and ownership on `/var` (`ls -lR /var`)