# Sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have setuid bit set

Tags: permissions, root

Help I'm stuck. My login page was looping I checked online came here and most solutions didn't work for instance I didn't have the .Xauthority file listed when I ran the command `ls -lah`, so I stumbled on a solution which people said worked , `chown -R $HOME:$HOME` sudo so now if I type commands like `ls -ld /usr /usr/bin` I get `drwxr-xr-x 10 Mickey Mickey` and `drwxr-xr-x 2 Mickey mickey`, and my computer is in low graphics mode I can only access it through tty3. Please I don't want to loose my files.

Answer (score 0):

O.k. since you're able to TTY login do the following:

```
sudo chown -R <your-user-name>:<your-user-name> /home/<your-user-name>
```

After that make sure `.Xauthority` is renewed when you next log in delete it or rename it.

```
mv /home/<your-user-name>/<your-user-name>{,.disabled}
```

But if you're indeed changed the owner of all files around your computer to your user you might be better off, saving your files to an external drive and reinstalling since reworking the proper users would be a pain and give you for sure a big headache in the long run.

If you having troubles getting your files onto an other drive this way you as well can use a live USB/CD and choose try Ubuntu and go from there.

Comment: I can't execute the first command it gives me the error I put as my topic

Comment: Added another option to at least get your hand onto your files, so you can backup and reinstall.

Comment: So I can use the second command to backup my files to my external hard drive ?

Comment: Please how can I back up my files from TTY login, thank you

Comment: No you have to boot as first from a live USB/CD and from there use a external drive to backup your data/files. the above commands only work if you messed up your own user directory, but as it looks now you're messed up your whole installation. See as well here http://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set?rq=1

Comment: Can you still `ls -a /home/<your-user-name>/` ?

Comment: But I only have an external hard drive so are you saying I can't back up now

Comment: Yes I can see files in my home dir

Comment: I didn't say you cant back up your files.

Comment: Oh okay , please how can I do that using only an external hard drive