# I set /usr/bin, /usr/lib, and /usr/share to be owned by my regular user and now I am getting interesting errors

Tags: permissions, chown

After running this command - `sudo chown -R $(whoami) usr/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}` I am not able to run sudo anymore: `sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`. How do I fixed that?

I read [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set) but I am not sure what advice to follow and if it's applicable to my case.

Comment: try this `chown -R root usr/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`

Comment: I get 'Operation not permitted'. i'll try following Kaz's steps below. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, we need to clean up the mess made of your system first. You'll need to boot into [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/150367/208574) first, because you need root for this.

1. **Fix `/usr/bin`**
   First off, we need to fix your binaries. Run the below command to repair all binaries and let `root` re-take ownership:

   ```
   chown -R root /usr/bin
   ```
2. **Fix `setuid` binaries**
   Now that `/usr/bin` is fixed, we can focus on all the binaries that lost their `setuid` status. The `setuid` flag is a special executable flag that allows for an executable to run as the owning user, as opposed to the calling user. Run the below commands to fix this:

   ```
   chmod u+s chfn chsh gpasswd newgrp passwd pkexec sudo
   ```
3. **Fix `/usr/lib`**
   Similarly to step 1, we need to reassign everything in `/usr/lib` to the root user.

   ```
   chown -R root /usr/lib
   ```
4. **Fix `/usr/share`**
   This one is a *much* more involved process because things in `/usr/share` could (possibly) be owned by non-root users. For now, you're going to have to restore all permissions to `root`, and then fix any problems that come up as they come up. Be sure to watch your log files for any permission errors or the like.

   ```
   chown -R root /usr/share
   ```
5. **Reboot and Pray**
   Running commands like `chown` and `chmod` recursively on system folders without knowing *exactly* what you're doing is very dangerous. While it is *occasionally* possible to recover from a mess like this, it's not always possible. You (fortunately) only really reverted folders where everything is owned by `root`, so fixing problems is pretty simple. But, it is important to know that this *could* have ended with you being forced to reinstall your entire system. You've also dodged a bullet by not overwriting groups -- that could have very easily been catastrophic.

Don't mess around with `chown`/`chmod`, and if you're using those commands with `sudo`, **you're *probably* doing something wrong**. Double- and triple-check what you're doing and make sure what you want to do is sane. Also make sure your commands are free of typos.

Also be sure you're not getting into the habit of prefixing everything that doesn't work with `sudo` -- this is a one-step method to destroying a Linux install because of carelessness.

Comment: Works! for anyone else reading this. I don't have 'pxexec' so I had to omit that executable from your second command. Also, [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) are the instructions I used to get into recovery mode.

Comment: @roy, Hey sorry, that was a typo. Re-run that command with `pkexec` please, just to be safe.