# I accidentally chown'd /usr/lib... what do I do now?

Tags: 18.04, permissions

I made a terrible mistake. I realized it right after I did it, but now it is too late.

I ran this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/lib
```

and I tried to fix it with:

```
sudo chown -R root /usr/lib
```

but I get this error:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy"
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

I tried to log in as root with:

```
su
```

but authentication failed every time. I'm 99% sure I have my password right.

I figured I owned the files now, so I also tried:

```
chown -R root /usr/lib
```

But the operation fails. I get what appears to be a long list of an the same error for changing the permission of every file. Each line looks like this:

```
chown: changing ownership of 'lib': Operation not permitted
```

Is there anything I can do to save myself?

Comment: You will need to boot into a live system, mount your disk, and change ownership. You're probably lucky, as ownership of files under `/usr/lib` is most probably all `root`. So it should be a relatively easy fix, granted you boot into a live system. You should be able to find more info (by order of importance to your case), [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/874782/8698), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode), [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/300641/8698) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/43621/8698).

Comment: I think you have pointed me in the right direction, thank you. Is "boot[ing] into a live system" the same as booting into recovery mode?

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion, no you don't need to boot into a live system. Recovery mode is enough. I was mistaken there. No, they are not the same by the way, to boot into a live system, it means you boot another Ubuntu instance from a USB pen drive or from a disk drive.