# Permission denied to create a symbolic link; sudo errors out

Tags: 14.04, permissions, php, symbolic-link

I am trying to install phalcon development tools. In the documentation they said:

**Create a symbolic link to the phalcon.php script:**

```
ln -s ~/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php /usr/bin/phalcon
chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/phalcon
```

and after connecting to my Ubuntu server, at the step of creating symbolic link to the `phalcon.php` script I get an error:

```
ubuntu@ip-000-00-0-00:/$ sudo ln -s ~/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php /usr/bin/phalcon
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

How can I complete the installation?

When I try without `sudo` I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-000-00-0-00:/$ ln -s ~/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php /usr/bin/phalcon
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/phalcon’: Permission denied
```

[Documentation which I followed](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/devtools-installation)

I have tried all the answers from this question but still getting same errors: [/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set)

Comment: i have tried all the answers but still im getting the same errors.

Comment: seems like you've broken `sudo` - or do you only get this error when you try to make this particular symbolic link? Could you tell us about your environment?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo`? It looks like sudo's permissions are messed up. The sudo binary needs the setuid bit, and has to be owned by root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `/usr/bin/sudo` is broken as mentioned. You can try to fix it by booting your linux machine in `recovery mode` and fixing it by running the commands:

- Change owner back to root (uid 0) `chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo`
- Fix permissions ONLY IF THEY ARE INCORRECT. Run `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo` and permissions should be `-rwsr-xr-x`. If they are not, fix them by running `chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo`.

If all goes well then you should have `sudo` back!