# Fix changing all files permissions to default user in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, recovery-mode, password-recovery

I accidentally ran the command

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu .
```

while i was in the root directory.
Now every single files user and group has changed to the Ubuntu user and group. And none of the commands `sudo`, `pkexec` are working because permissions of /etc/sudoers.d file is incorrect. IS there any way I can recover. I cant login as root using password since it was not configured.

Is there any way I can fix this? logging in as root is sufficient for me to change the permissions back, as `chown` command works only as root.

This matter is extremely urgent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Accidental sudo chown. How do I recover?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987531/accidental-sudo-chown-how-do-i-recover)

Answer (score 0):

Either boot into single-user mode via grub, or boot from a liveCD or USB stick. Either of these should give you access to the filesystem so that you can change file ownership. (When booting from CD/USB, you will probably have to manually mount the filesystem.)