# How to fix sudo chown -R :NewGroup /usr?

Tags: sudo

I run the following command:

```
  sudo chown -R :NewGroup /usr <--- I changed the assigned Group not the owner
```

Then, I get the following error:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/471503/155411. Give that a try.

Comment: Sounds like you broke `sudo`...

Comment: See my answer here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the replay. All this answers are for a change in the owner of the folder I didn't change the owner. I changed the group, all the dirs in the /usr are owned by root and now them are assigned to "newGroup". Is in this case still necessary to reninstall the whole OS?

Comment: The answers there will work the same with a very slight modification, still use the same command, especially my answer, which will reset all ownership, owner and group.