# Does chown or chmod generate write reques when they need not change anything?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, chown

Do utilities `chown` and `chmod` perform actual writing to the file when the settings they were instructed to set are already what file has? For example:

```
> ls -l 

... gooduser gods ... state_secrets

> chown gooduser:gods state_secrets
```

Should I use `find` to find files that need changes, or would just `chmod -R` be more effective ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice way to find out whether `chown` actually changes ownership 
of files even if they stay the same (e.g. from `pduck` to `pduck`)
is to run the command under `strace`. This way we can see the APIs 
that actually get called.

I created a test file which is owned by me and my group. 
Then I did `chown pduck:pduck test.txt` but with `strace` 
prepended:

```
$ touch test.txt
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 pduck pduck 0 Jun 16 12:10 test.txt

$ strace chown pduck:pduck test.txt
execve("/bin/chown", ["chown", "pduck:pduck", "test.txt"], 0x7ffd0309c990 /* 74 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5589645df000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "test.txt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
fchownat(AT_FDCWD, "test.txt", 1000, 1000, 0) = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

As we can see, the ownership is indeed unconditionally *changed* from 
pduck:pduck to 1000:1000 (which are the numerical IDs of pduck:pduck).

---

You have multiple options:

- `chown --from=pduck:pduck pgoose:pgoose text.txt`
  Will only change the ownership to `pgoose:pgoose` if it currently is `pduck:pduck`.
  Files with other ownerships remain untouched. Add `-R` to make the changes
  recursively.
- `find . -type f -user pduck -group pduck -exec chown pgoose:pgoose {} +`
  This will (recursively) find all files owned by pduck:pduck and only 
  for them run `chown pgoose:pgoose …`.
- `find . -type f -not -\( -user pduck -or -group pduck -\) -exec chown pduck:pduck {} +`
  Changes ownership of files that do not belong to user `pduck` or group `pduck`.

As long as you don't have hundreds of thousands of files I don't think there is 
much difference in the performance.

When I do `chown -R ...` then usually because a whole directory has "wrong" ownership
(for example on thumbdrives). But I usually ***never*** do `chmod -R` because files
and directories need different permissions and the `x` has a different meaning for them.
We have many questions here on how to fix that terrible `chmod -R 777 …` thing.
Instead, I do it in two separate commands (`find -type d …` and `find -type f …`).

Comment: Many systems are effectively single user systems. In this case, the +x for directories doesn't matter *too much*. While I agree that being careful about `chmod -R`, the execute bit is not my worry. As [seen on this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set), `chown -R user:user /` seems to be a bigger problem ;)