# Wrong chown on root /

Tags: permissions, root, chown

There are lot of questions regarding the same mistake , What i did was :

> chown -R root:www-data myfolder /

by mistake i typed a space between the folder & / . Then i was not able to do sudo any more . After following [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set/471503#471503) i was able to do sudo again . But my concern is will this going to break my system in the future ? would be there any issue in the future reboots ?

I still not closed the connected ssh as root . The server is used only as a webserver .

Comment: It's an issue already. I'd recommend to reinstall.

Comment: On a stock Ubuntu system, that command should have none nothing at all (no 'sudo'). However, if you used 'sudo', or were (unwisely) using a root prompt, then that command would damage your system beyond convenient repair. Backup your data (fix it too; Your data now has the wrong ownership) and then reinstall.

Comment: The server has no other user accounts . My concern is will this breaks the booting ? I cant even think about it 

Comment: Exactly which release of Ubuntu is this server running?

Comment: The server version is : Ubuntu 18.04.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fatal error. There is no way you can correctly restore the file permissions. So, reinstall or restore from a system backup.

Comment: Until this day, there isn't any problems. Tried restarting also. But i accept this answer, considering the depth if the issue that could impact on the system.

Comment: As such, you may not have had issues because the command made `root` owner of every last file on the system, but indeed, it is fundamentally impossible to restore the ownerships to their original state (which for system files will be root:root in the majority of cases anyway).

Comment: completely agree with you