# I've mistakenly run "sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /"

Tags: sudo

I've mistakenly run "sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /". Now I can't login through ssh, it shows this message "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset".
What should I do now?

Comment: No, I haven't any backup. There is no way to rollback?

Comment: or https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set?noredirect=1&lq=1