# Ubuntu 18.04 unable to login as user, but can login in tty3

Tags: permissions, login, sudo, chown

I accidentally messed up the permissions by typing `sudo chown -R root:root /usr`. It was supposed to `usr` instead of `/usr`. anyway, I lost sudo function and showed the error message `sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`. But I followed this thread https://askubuntu.com/a/471503/1127900 and solved that issue.

But after that I rebooted and tried to login my user. After typing the password I am getting the login window again and again, but no password incorrect message. But login using tty3 is a success.

Please help to fix this problem. I am in a severe headache with this.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `/usr/bin/sudo` **should** be `root:root` - so it's not clear why the command you mention should have caused that particular error

Comment: but the problem started after running `sudo chown -R root:root /usr`. Is there anything that I can do to check where is my mistake?

Comment: solved myself by `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core  xserver-xorg-input-all`.