# WIfi adapter not found and software updater not working

Tags: wireless, software-center, update-manager

I am trying to change the permissions of a folder on my PC and I mistakenly ran:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /
```

without indicating the directory, and now `sudo` isn't working. It's showing:

```
/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid
```

I tried some suggestions found on this forum and am able to fix it through the boot up recovery mode, but not most of the applications don't work. The Wi-Fi is not working anymore. It's showing:

```
No Wi-Fi adapter found
```

Also Software & Updates is not working anymore.

Is there anyone that can help me? I would appreciate that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set](https://askubuntu.com/q/452860/)

Comment: Restore files from a backup; or you can take note of what permissions/file-stats exist on those backup files & use that as a template of how to reverse the changes (*that is possibly a good learning exercise*)... An alternative is to re-install (which needn't overwrite files & it can auto re-install your *manually installed* if from Ubuntu repositories too if you don't format; but restore will be necessary if you're using server apps!)