# Rstudio desktop "unable to open the base package"

Tags: 18.04, rstudio

I'm running R 4.1.2 on my Linux system (18.04.6 LTS, "Bionic Beaver"), and am able to run R code in Terminal fine. I recently installed RStudio Desktop (2022.02.0+443, "Prairie Trillium"), but when I try to run it I get a pop up window saying "unable to open base package".

[image: RStudio_Error_SUICIDE]

Resetting the R user's state (per [this suggestion, for a similar issue in rstudio-server](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-r-suicide-error-r-error-4-r-code-execution-error/72131)) did nothing.

**Context**: I had a serious permissions issues on this server recently where the ownership of /usr was accidentally changed; see the thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set), which I followed in order to fix the problem. It seemed to work, but now RStudio is still giving me troubles.

I've scoured the Internet, but with no luck. Uninstalling/reinstalling RStudio doesn't seem to fix anything.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit**: Output of `apt-cache policy r-base-dev`:

```
r-base-dev:
  Installed: 4.1.2-1.1804.0
  Candidate: 4.1.2-1.1804.0
  Version table:
 *** 4.1.2-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.1.1-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.0-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.5-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.4-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.3-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     3.4.4-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev --reinstall` and then run RStudio again.

Comment: Still getting the same error ("unable to open the base package") after this. The same text is written to the rstudio log (~/.local/share/rstudio/log/rsession-akoontz.log): 

ERROR R SUICIDE: unable to open the base package; LOGGED FROM: void {anonymous}::rSuicide(const string&) src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:1206

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy r-base-dev` to the question.

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert, see edit

Comment: Also: RStudio will open when called from `root`, but it gives the message `QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory /run/user/1001, 1001 instead of 0`. Any other user besides `root` generates described behavior

Comment: Can't reproduce on fresh VM. You can try moving R folder out the way by `mv ~/R ~/R-old` and then run RStudio again.

Comment: Moving `/usr/bin/R` didn't address the problem (not sure if you meant this or something else; on the user account in question, there is no `~/R` directory). 

I suspect this is somehow tied to the permissions on either the R executable or other relevant R folders (since rstudio functions under `root`), but I couldn't say which ones. I'm trying to fix that now.

Answer (score 1):

I ultimately had to uninstall R in addition to RStudio to address this problem. This somehow righted the permission structure and allowed RStudio to open for non-root users.