# su and sudo commond could not work

Tags: sudo, su

apt install and update commands need the read and write of root or administrators. but it does not work now.

```
$ sudo 
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
$ su
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Comment: What did you change on your system?

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; but your issue is likely the consequence of some mistake you've made, corrupting file meta data with a `chmod`, changed mounts etc, of which you've provided no details on your *unstated* OS/release.

Comment: This error hints that you broke your system by doing a system-wide ownership  change. Did you?  Reinstall and don't do it again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set)