# Permission erros on fresh installations - New to Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, virtualbox

I have installed Ubunto on VirtualBox and I don't have permissions to do anything.
I have reinstalled it twice and it seems the fresh installation does not provide my user with permissions.

I tried installing Nodejs using sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
and did manage someone to install it, then tried installing some package in node and had no permissions of doing so.

I reinstalled and tried installing Node with files from the official website and move them into /usr/ directory(?) and had no permissions of doing so.

Any solution online that I found with sudo command ends up with:
"sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set"

What do I do? I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

Comment: You've not told us what Ubuntu product you installed (Desktop?, Server?, Core?) not what release, nor if you allocated sufficient space for the install to operation (Desktop requires more space than a Server install & we don't know if you provided the minimum requirements for the *unstated* Ubuntu product you installed), thus cannot current advice much.  Please be specific with details.  What Ubuntu product?, what release?  Did you create sufficient disk space for your VM for that product? etc.

Comment: It sounds like you mistakenly changed some important file ownerships - see for example [/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set)