# im unable to run sudo command

Tags: permissions, sudo

```
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

im unable to use `sudo` probably when i tried to change the acxess permisiion of read and write to every one:

(1) me group and others

(2)i ran this command i guess when i was updating snap and it was giving error

```
$ sudo chown -R aryan /
```

i just upgraded to 23.04 ubuntu
im also unable to apen additional dri

[image]

ver app can find wifi bluetooth is buggy
plzzz help it took me whole day to upgrade set customize my laptop

these are things what i tried

Comment: If I were you, I would backup my data and reinstall Ubuntu ... You have recursively changed ownership of everything on your system and damaged it severely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set)

Comment: `sudo chown -R aryan /` - This is one of those command you must never run - and now you know why. As Raffa says, you've damaged more than `sudo` with this command.

Comment: In future, please don't run random commands from the internet without knowing what they do.

Answer (score 1):

The command `sudo chown -R aryan /` will destroy an Ubuntu system, making it unbootable. So that seems an unwise command for you to run.

Use a LiveUSB to preserve your data to some other media.

Then use the same LiveUSB to reinstall Ubuntu.