# Problem with sudo

Tags: sudo, chown

```
sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

So I can't make any changes or install anything.
ubuntu 22.04
I am just start study it

appreciate your help

Comment: Please enter `ls -l $(which sudo)` and add its output to your question. Also please state your Ubuntu version.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Is it a desktop, server, or cloud instance? [Add all information we ask in comments, to your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506584/edit)

Comment: Have you done any chmod, chown or similar commands lately ? Please add them to your question.

Comment: You tagged your question "upgrade" - did you upgrade your Ubuntu and sudo stopped working? if yes, from which version did you upgrade?

Comment: Edited to remove seemingly-irrelevant tags. Looks like you perhaps destroyed your system while tinkering. It can probably be repaired, but showing us exactly what you did is likely to make the repair much easier. We are not clairvoyant. If you don't want to share what you did, then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set)

Comment: @tour-waltinator thanks for help I will check the documents

Comment: @all thanks for your trying helping me