# Default owner of var 16.04

Tags: 16.04, chown, ownership

My problem is short. I have typed

```
chown -R root:root /var
```

and my mysql server stopped working :/ I tried searching for the solution, but nothing helped me.

I have also problem with permissions in Phpmyadmin. Errors you can found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/356gs.png).

I know, that i have ruined the whole structure of ownerhsip, so if you have a list of default users and groups in var I would be very gratefull.

Comment: also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/343245/default-user-group-owner-for-var-folder

Comment: even better: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49959/how-to-restore-default-group-user-ownership-of-all-files-under-var

Comment: Please consider providing text outputs instead of screenshots. It helps finding the question and improves formatting. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command was harmful. It changed the ownership of all objects (file and directories) inside `/var` directory to `root` user. But that is not what some programs expect, including `mysql`

`mysql` wants the files inside `/var/lib/mysql` directory to be owned by the user `mysql`.

So, you should change the ownership of the directory (recursively) again using this command

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Except this file `/var/lib/mysql/debian-5.7.flag`. That one is owned by `root`. After executing the above command, you can again change the ownership of this file

```
sudo chown root:root /var/lib/mysql/debian-5.7.flag
```

Also `mysql` wants the its log directory to be owned by `mysql` user. So, do this again to change ownership of that too

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
```

Fortuantely, I had `phpmyadmin` installed. I can give the files list owned by `mysql` in `/var/lib/phpmyadmin` directory. Here is the list. Change ownership of all of these using `sudo chown mysql:mysql filename` command.

```
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__table_uiprefs.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__bookmark.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__pdf_pages.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__usergroups.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__savedsearches.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__designer_settings.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__relation.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__export_templates.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__favorite.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__column_info.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__users.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__relation.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__table_coords.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__navigationhiding.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__column_info.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__history.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__tracking.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__export_templates.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__users.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__table_coords.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__table_info.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__table_info.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__savedsearches.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__central_columns.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__central_columns.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__history.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__favorite.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__table_uiprefs.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__recent.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__usergroups.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__navigationhiding.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__bookmark.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__designer_settings.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__tracking.ibd 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__pdf_pages.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma__recent.frm 
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/db.opt
```

I've answered this to fix only mysql related stuff. But if you need to fix all those, you can check these questions

- [Default user-group owner for /var folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343245/default-user-group-owner-for-var-folder)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49959/how-to-restore-default-group-user-ownership-of-all-files-under-var

Comment: @Rinzwind why? where am i doing wrong?

Comment: That's working :D But I have one problem more with phpmyadmin "Permission denied" in /var/lib/php/sessions :/ Full error: http://prntscr.com/czlgo2

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm fixing the stuff only in `/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: Is there any list of users and groups in var that now i have to set up?

Comment: @Kryniowesegryderiusz are you looking for answers for all files and dirs inside `/var/` or only mysql? I provided answer only for mysql

Comment: @Kryniowesegryderiusz add the screenshot and further errors to your question. Not in comments

Comment: I have ruined the whole var, so if you help me with all dirs I will be very grateful :)

Comment: @Kryniowesegryderiusz Have you found the links helpful? I can give my `/var`s permission entries for you. but without knowing what packages you installed, it is very hard to provide an exact fix